# How to use AJAX to send an array to a PHP file so it can be added to a mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ajax, cordova

I'm calling send Array function and I'm hoping to create and array and send it to my PHP file. I want the PHP to extract the data and enter the values into the columns in a mySQL database.

```
function sendArray(){

             var name = "John";
             var address = "UK"


             var sendInfo = {
                 Name: name,
                 Address: address,

                };


                $.ajax({
                       url: "http://server/~name/folder/insertOffer.php",
                       type: "POST",
                       dataType: "json",
                       data: {data: sendInfo},

                       })
                       .done(function(msg) {
                             if (msg) {
                             alert("Somebody" + name + " was added in list !");
                             location.reload(true);
                             } else {
                             alert("Cannot add to list !");
                             }
                             });

}

<?php

include("mysqlconnect.php");

$sendInfo = file_get_contents('php://input');

$data = [];

$Name = $_POST['data']['name'];
$Address = $_POST['data']['Address'];


mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO offerSelected (Id, Url)
VALUES ('$name', '$address')");

?>
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting

Answer (score 1):

You have one problem with your JS:

```
var sendInfo = {
    Name: name,
    Address: address,
};
```

Trailing commas can cause problems in some browsers. Remove the comma from after `address`.

When making the HTTP request you can either:

- Send JSON *or*
- Send form encoded data

(There are other options, but these are the ones relevant to the code you are using)

Your JavaScript is sending form encoded data, but your PHP is trying to perform a weird mix of parsing both.

```
$sendInfo = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Remove the above line. You are sending form encoded data. You don't need to get the raw input for manual parsing. PHP will parse form encoded data automatically and put it in `$_POST`.

```
$data = [];
```

Remove the above line. You never use `$data`.

```
$Name = $_POST['data']['name'];
```

You called the property `Name` in your JavaScript, not `name`. Be consistent. Change that to:

```
$Name = $_POST['data']['Name'];
```

Then:

```
$Address = $_POST['data']['Address'];
```

This should work fine by itself (given the JavaScript you have).

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO offerSelected (Id, Url) VALUES ('$name', '$address')");
```

You called your variables `$Name` and `$Address`. Don't change them to `$name` and `$address` in the middle of  your program.

Note, however, that once you fix that, you remain **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: I feel my javaScript isn't activating correctly my alert("Somebody" + name + " was added in list !") never functions. I'm running this script in a cordova app so it's difficult for me to view errors. The function is being called correctly however.

Comment: @MichaelO'Neill — Then you need to learn how to use cordova's debugging tools better to figure out what is actually going on.

Comment: I've found half a dozen problems with your code and no others leap out at me.